# Why can't I install this app/package in sandbox?

Tags: apex, trigger, package, install

I am trying to install the trigger framework mentioned [here](https://krishhari.wordpress.com/2013/07/22/an-architecture-framework-to-handle-triggers-in-the-force-com-platform/)

When I am installing this app in my sandbox (https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04tU00000005VdB) , It is always trying to install in my production environment.

I replaced the login.salesforce.com with test.salesforce.com but still it goes to prod.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: I was able to install it in my sandbox by going to https://test.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04tU00000005VdB and logging into my sandbox.  Try logging out of your production org, and try again.

Comment: I feel like stupid. It is working now.

Comment: Added the comment as an answer so you can close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to install it in my sandbox by going to test.salesforce.com/packaging/… and logging into my sandbox. Try logging out of your production org, and try again.